# Exceptions: “Bring” and “Take” for Future Events

Tags: grammaticality, difference

1. [As one listener named Simone put it, you bring things here and take things there.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/bring-versus-take)

2. [If you want to focus on the school and write from the perspective of the bazaar, **you bring the cake to the bazaar**.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/bring-versus-take?page=1).

How's 2 a sensible exception? The bolded requires that I be here (at the bazaar). So how can the bolded make sense if I'm already here? Why not **take** for both 'perspectives' (From home and the bazaar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know as I completely agree with Simone's characterization.

*Bring* is used when you are focusing on your *arrival* somewhere and the things you have with you when you arrive.
 *Take* is used when you are focusing on your *departure* and the things you have with you when you depart.

When you bring the cake to the bazaar you are speaking about your arrival at the bazaar and that you have a cake with you. Your origin is secondary and unspecified.

When you take the cake from home, you are speaking about your departure from your house and that you took the cake from your house. Your destination is secondary and unspecified.

When you take the cake to the bazaar you are talking about your departure, from an unspecified origin, with the cake. Your destination (the bazaar) is secondary.

When you bring the cake from home, you are talking about your arrival at your destination (unspecified) with the cake. Your origin (home) is secondary.

And finally you can take the cake from home and bring it to the bazaar.
Now you've got both ends fully covered and at equal importance.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to either *bring* or *take* the cake to the bazaar — both verbs can be used here, and have essentially the same meaning. There is a subtle difference in emphasis, but as long as you're explicitly saying *where* you're taking (or bringing) the cake, the two verbs are all but synonymous.

The situation where the verbs "take" and "bring" differ in meaning is when you *don't* specify where you're taking / bringing the object.  In that case, the implied destination for "bring" is "here", while that for "take" is "away".

(More precisely, "take" without an explicit destination generally implies movement towards the *speaker*, whereas "bring" suggests movement *with* the speaker towards the *listener*, or towards the location being discussed.)

For example, if you said:

> *I went to the party and brought the cake.*

you'd be saying that the cake was not at the party before you brought it there.  On the other hand, if you said:

> *I went to the party and took the cake.*

you'd be implying that the cake *was* at the party before you took it away, but now it's gone.